# Confusion in size of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, size, numpy-ndarray

Python numpy array 'size' confuses me a lot

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
a.size = (3, )
------------------------
b = np.array([[2,1,3,5],
             [2,2,5,1],
             [3,6,99,5]])
b.size = (3,4)
```

'b' makes sense since it has 3 rows and 4 columns in each
But how is 'a' size = (3, ) ? Shouldn't it be (1,3) since its 1 row and 3 columns?

Comment: In geometry, what's the width of a line?  A pure line has only one dimension, length.

Answer (score 2):

You should resist the urge to think of `numpy` arrays as having *rows* and *columns*, but instead consider them as having *dimensions* and *shape*. This is an important point which differentiates `np.array` and `np.matrix`:

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
print(x.ndim, x.shape)  # 1 (3,)

y = np.matrix([1, 2, 3])
print(y.ndim, y.shape)  # 2 (1, 3)
```

An *n*-D array can only use *n* integer(s) to represent its shape. Therefore, a 1-D array only uses 1 integer to specify its shape.

In practice, combining calculations between 1-D and 2-D arrays is not a problem for `numpy`, and syntactically clean since `@` matrix operation was introduced in Python 3.5. Therefore, there is rarely a need to resort to `np.matrix` in order to satisfy the urge to see expected row and column counts.

In the rare instances where 2 dimensions are required, you can still use `numpy.array` with some manipulation:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])[:, None]  # equivalent to np.array([[1], [2], [3]])
print(a.ndim, a.shape)  # 2 (3, 1)

b = np.array([[1, 2, 3]])  # equivalent to np.array([1, 2, 3])[:, None].T
print(b.ndim, b.shape)  # 2 (1, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

No, a `numpy.ndarray` with shape (1, 3) would look like:

```
np.array([[1,2,3]])
```

Think about how the shape corresponds to indexing:

```
arr[0, ...]  #First row
```

I still have three more options, namely:

```
arr[0,0]
arr[0,1]
arr[0,2]
```

Try doing that with a 1 dimensional array

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant `ndarray.shape`. In that case, there's no need for confusion. Quoting the documentation from `ndarray.shape`:

> Tuple of array dimensions.

`ndarray.shape` simply returns a shape tuple.

```
In [21]: a.shape
Out[21]: (3,)
```

This simply means that `a` is an 1D array with 3 entries.

If the shape tuple returns it as `(1,3)` then `a` would become a 2D array. For that you need to use:

```
In [23]: a = a[np.newaxis, :]

In [24]: a.shape
Out[24]: (1, 3)
```

Since array `b` is 2D, the shape tuple has two entries.

```
In [22]: b.shape
Out[22]: (3, 4)
```