# Python array rows*1column numpy for numpy.dot(matrix,matrix2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Is
 `a = [1, 2, 3]
 x = numpy.array(a)`

 a matrix of 3 cols and 1 row? I know that `x = numpy.array([a])` is a 1x4 matrix but i need the opossite.
I need to multiply two matrix but the first one is a list inserted into a `numpy.array(a)`

have not found the doc for a way to do a for and cicle throught a to add it to x. 
Edit: I am working on linear regression so i need a nrows x 1 col, my original data is in a list and am using numpy dot() funtion to multiply and i need to transform my list int a matrix nrowsx 1 column.
Fixed the solution was to transpose x = numpy.array([a]) with x = x.transpose() and that gives me a nx1 matrix.

Thanks for the help given you helped me think.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confusion in size of a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48727120/confusion-in-size-of-a-numpy-array)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `a list insert into an array`.

Comment: @jpp saw that question, but i am asking how to make a many rows one column matrix, I will edit my question to add that I am using numpy.dot(matrix1, matrix)

Comment: @hpaulj I have not read that in particular, will do a quick google search on list insert into an array and see if i get my desired result.

Comment: You have 3 elements. Beyond the mistake of thinking a 1D array has rows and columns, where did you get the idea it had *4* columns?

Comment: @user2357112 Are you serius? you did not think i made a mistake and pressed 4 instead of 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a 1 dimensional array:

```
In [653]: x = np.array([1,2,3])
In [654]: x
Out[654]: array([1, 2, 3])
In [655]: x.shape
Out[655]: (3,)
In [656]: x.ndim
Out[656]: 1
```

The other is 2 dimensional:

```
In [657]: y = np.array([[1,2,3]])
In [658]: y
Out[658]: array([[1, 2, 3]])
In [659]: y.shape
Out[659]: (1, 3)
In [660]: y.ndim
Out[660]: 2
```

the transpose of `y`

```
In [661]: z = y.T
In [662]: z
Out[662]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
In [663]: z.shape
Out[663]: (3, 1)
```

The transpose of `x` is the same as `x`

---

Some multiply options:

```
In [664]: np.dot(x,y)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-664-6849a5f7ad6c> in <module>()
----> 1 np.dot(x,y)

ValueError: shapes (3,) and (1,3) not aligned: 3 (dim 0) != 1 (dim 0)
```

Read `np.dot` for rules about the interaction of shapes. The key phrase is 'last dimension of x pairs the 2nd to the last of y'.

```
In [665]: np.dot(y,x)
Out[665]: array([14])
```

Here the (1,3) pairs with (3,) t- produce a (1,).

Element wise multiplication.  Here broadcasting rules apply

```
In [666]: x*y   
Out[666]: array([[1, 4, 9]])
```

(3,) with (1,3) -> (1,3)(1,3) -> (1,3)

```
In [667]: x*z
Out[667]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 4, 6],
       [3, 6, 9]])
```

(3,) with (3,1) -> (1,3)(3,1) -> (3,3)

---

A handy way of changing the (3,) array into a (3,1) is with `None` (`np.newaxis`):

```
In [671]: x[:,None]
Out[671]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])

In [672]: np.dot(x[:,None],y)
Out[672]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 4, 6],
       [3, 6, 9]])
```

(3,1) dot with (1,3) -> (3,3)

Comment: but if I am multiplying two matrix as in z = numpy.dot(x*y) will x be considered a 3x1 matrix or not? i take it for your answer that I will just get an ugly error message, and i am doing a linear regression and for it i need to turn a list into a matrix of as many rows as items in the list, i just dont know how.