# Create 2D matrices from several csv files

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, csv, numpy

**I'm working with Python3 and I would like to load datas from several CSV files.**
Each CSV (one measurement) has 3 columns (3 different physical quantities). I want to load each quantity on 3 separate variables. For one CSV file this is quite simple, I used :

```
TIME,CH1,CH2 = loadtxt(file_path,usecols=(3,4,5),delimiter=',',skiprows=2,unpack=True)
```

and it worked fine. Now **I would like to extend this procedure so I can load several CSV files**. Each array would be 2D, each column representing one CSV file. Instead of having several CSV with three variables, I will have 3 2D arrays, which is much more convenient for data analysis.

I thought I could try something like this :

```
TIME = matrix(zeros((20480,len(file_path)))) # 20480 length of each column
CH1 = matrix(zeros((20480,len(file_path)))) # len(file_path) number of CSV files
CH2 = matrix(zeros((20480,len(file_path))))
for k in range(0,len(file_path)): # reading each CSV file
    TIME[:,k],CH1[:,k],CH2[:,k] = loadtxt(file_path[k],usecols=(3,4,5),delimiter=',',skiprows=2,unpack=True)
```

But it's telling me :

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (20480) into shape (20480,1)
```

*In the end I would like variables looking like this :*

```
TIME = matrix([[0., 0., 0.],
               [0., 0., 0.],
               [0., 0., 0.],
               ...,
               [0., 0., 0.],
               [0., 0., 0.],
               [0., 0., 0.]])
```

**Each column is from one different CSV file.**

I think this is a quite usual problem, but I don't really get how arrays works in Python. I get this idea from Matlab which is quite straightforward but here I don't know why indexing arrays with TIME[:][:] doesn't work.

Have you any idea how I could do this ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use `np.array`, not `np.matrix`

I can't emphasize this enough. `np.matrix` exists only for legacy reasons. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48727191/9209546) for an explanation of the difference. `np.matrix` requires 2 dimensions, while `np.array` permits a single dimension when indexing. This seems to be the source of your error.

Here's a minimal example exhibiting the behaviour you are seeing:

```
A = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
B = np.matrix(A)

print(A[:, 0].shape)  # (2,)
print(B[:, 0].shape)  # (2, 1)
```

Therefore, define your resultant arrays as `np.array` objects:

```
m = 20480
n = len(file_path)
shape = (m, n)

TIME = np.zeros(shape)
CH1 = np.zeros(shape)
CH2 = np.zeros(shape)
```

Comment: Almost want to edit just to put that first line in 36 point font.